# iOS Notification using swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to run a small app which runs timer based notification. Code is written in swift.

Inside appdelegate::func application(...) ---

```
        let notificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
    let acceptAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    acceptAction.identifier = "Accept"
    acceptAction.title = "Accept"
    acceptAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
    acceptAction.destructive = false
    acceptAction.authenticationRequired = false

    let declineAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    declineAction.identifier = "Decline"
    declineAction.title = "Decline"
    declineAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
    declineAction.destructive = false
    declineAction.authenticationRequired = false

    let category = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
    category.identifier = "invite"
    category.setActions([acceptAction,declineAction], forContext:
        UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)
    let catergories = NSSet(array: [category])
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationType, categories: catergories)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
```

Inside view controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var timer = NSTimer();

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    invokeNotification()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func startNotify(sender: AnyObject) {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: Selector("invokeNotification"),userInfo: nil, repeats: true);
}

@IBAction func stopNofity(sender: AnyObject) {
    timer.invalidate();
}

func invokeNotification() {
    var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.alertAction = "Testing notifications on iOS8"
    localNotification.alertBody = "Local notifications are working"
    localNotification.fireDate = nil
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    localNotification.category = "invite"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
}
```

}

Problem is on device when I press Start and move app to background it does not generate notification when run on device, but works for me on simulator.

(PS: I have tried using `acceptAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Foreground` as well and it did not help either )

Any help appreciated

Comment: Not really, when the app runs on device, app gets killed. So essentially only way I figured out was to do fake location query, so that app can stay alive.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is set a fireDate for the notification:

```
var date = NSDate()
var newDate = date.dateByAddingTimeInterval(3) //3 seconds from now

var not = UILocalNotification()
not.fireDate = newDate
not.alertBody = "Congratilations! Notification works!"

UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(not)
```